# Does Logback SMTPAppender support environment variables?

Tags: java, logging, logback, smtpappender

Inside the definition for a Logback `SMTPAppender`, you can specify email configuration info like so:

```
<smtpHost>my.smtp.host</smtpHost>
<to>john.smith@example.com</to>
<from>no-reply@example.com</from>
<username>my_smtp_user</username>
<password>my_smtp_password</password>
<subject>%logger{20} - %m</subject>
```

Instead of hardcoding the `<to>john.smith@example.com</to>` field, I'd like it to pick up the local username of whatever account/machine the Java app is running on. For instance, if my Ubuntu username is `ticketMonster`, then I would like the `<to>` field to be:

```
<to>ticketMonster@example.com</to>
```

Or if my operating system username is `bgates`, I'd like it to be:

```
<to>bgates@example.com</to>
```

Hence, I'm looking for *dynamic* username evaluation. I tried:

```
<to>${username}@example.com</to>
```

But that does not work... Any ideas or suggestions here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: One solution is to configure your appenders programmatically with a `JoranConfigurator`.

Comment: Variable substitution should work. Which version of logback are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable substitution for the `<to>` element should work. If it does not, it's a bug. Could you please create a new issue [on our jira](http://jira.qos.ch) so that this problem can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, There are few ways you can do it:

1. You can define your username in properties file and load your .properties file in logback.xml file.

   property resource="filename.properties"

   ```
   <username>${username}</username>
   <password>${password}</password>
   <to>${email1}</to>
   <from>${from}</from>
   ```
2. You can use System variable like this in logback.xml file

   < property name="user" value="${username}"/>